# bounce and zoom only first cell of uitableview like 'OYO' app of iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift

I have uitableview in my iphone application.

My UITableViewCell has only one imageView.

There are such 7 uitableviewcells available with my uitableview.

Upto now I have done correctly. Below is the image where I have problem. The first cell not getting stacked to top edge of UITableView. See below image. Thus Not getting actual zooming effect when pulls down and drag scroll in downward direction (i.e. contentOffset.Y negative). Part of first cell hides behind second cell.

[image]

below is my code

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    if (scrollView == _tvMaharajPics) {

        if (scrollView.contentOffset.y <= 0) {
            UITableViewCell *cell = [_tvMaharajPics cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0]];
            CGRect frame = cell.frame;
            frame.size.height = (self.view.frame.size.width * (3.0 / 4.0)) - scrollView.contentOffset.y;
            cell.frame = frame;
        }
    }

    // To disable bounce in bottom direction of UITableView
    if (scrollView.contentOffset.y >= scrollView.contentSize.height - scrollView.frame.size.height) {
        CGPoint offset = scrollView.contentOffset;
        offset.y = scrollView.contentSize.height - scrollView.frame.size.height;
        scrollView.contentOffset = offset;
    }
}
```

I only want to bounce and show zoom image effect in first cell only when user pulls down and drag scroll in downward direction (i.e. contentOffset.Y negative).

"SIMILAR EFFECT IS DEMONSTRATED IN 'OYO' APP WHEN USER LOOKS INTO ROOM IMAGES"

Answer (score 1):

You can swap the contents of the tableview cell (1st) to the tableview header and use this library to achieve this effect easily.

[GSKStretchyHeaderView](https://github.com/gskbyte/GSKStretchyHeaderView)

Or if you want to code yourself then use this tutorial to create this effect
[Tuturial](http://blog.matthewcheok.com/design-teardown-stretchy-headers/)
. Just remove the masking part from it.